# Global variable assigned inside while loop not available outside the loop

Tags: while-loop, scope, arduino, esp8266

I'm calling an api using ESP8266 WiFi Chip. Im declaring a global variable to assign the token sent by the server to it. The variable assignment is made inside a while loop. In this loop i'm reading the contents of the reply "the token" and saving it in the global variable.
But when i print out the result outside the while loop to variable is empty. But inside the loop it is not.

```
String deviceToken;

WiFiClient client;

  if (!client.connect(hostIp, 80)){
    Serial.println("Connection to server failed.");
    Serial.print(client.connect(hostIp, 80));
    return;
  }

    String authURL = "/api/";
      authURL += "startauth/";
      authURL += serialValue;
      Serial.print("Requesting URL: ");
      Serial.println(authURL);

      // This will send auth request to the server
      client.print(String("GET ") + authURL + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
                   "Host: " + host + "\r\n" + 
                   "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
     unsigned long timeout = millis();
     while (client.available() == 0) {
        if (millis() - timeout > 5000) {
          Serial.println(">>> Client Timeout !");
          client.stop();
          return;
        }
     }
    // Read Auth reply from server and print them to Serial
      while(client.available()){
        String token = client.readStringUntil('\r');
        deviceToken = token;
        writeDeviceToken(token.c_str());  //Function to write data in eeprom
        Serial.print(deviceToken); //NOT EMPTY
      }

      Serial.print("Device Token:" + deviceToken);  //EMPTY VARIABLE
```

[image]

Comment: Are you *sure* that the `deviceToken` is non-empty on the last iteration? Could you effectively be calling `Serial.print("")` one or more times at the end, causing this issue?

Comment: @Phylogenesis yes seems like this is the issue when i removed the token print it removed the "0" after it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your while loop you are looping over the HTTP headers and the data line by line and overwrite `deviceToken` each time. This is ok, except that each line ends with `\r\n` and not only `\r` - (also, you probably only want to write the token to the eeprom, not every header).

So the last token that gets read is a single `\n` which is then put into `deviceToken`. You will need to read that extra byte after each line.

An alternative way would be to read until you reach `\r\n\r\n` (end of header block), then read the size (28 hex - this is a [chunked transfer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chunked_transfer_encoding)), and then you can read and store the token you want. Otherwise your token would be that last `0`, or the newline following it.

Also keep in mind that there is no guarantee that the reply will allways be chunked (which is actually rather strange in this case), and you should be prepared for a 'normal' reply too.

An easy way to fix this, is to send a `HTTP/1.0` request instead of `HTTP/1.1` (as far as that server supports it). Since `HTTP/1.0` doesn't support/allow chunked transfers you will always have a 'clean' `deviceToken` in the reply.

Comment: That was the answer i was waiting for. Thankss. What i tried to do now is use '\n'. And removed the writingToEEPROM outside the loop. And i think it is working this way. The token is added in the next url string to make a new api call. But unfortunately i'm receiving 400 bad request. I tested the printed url on the serial in postman it is working properly.

Comment: @KeghamK. Your token probably has a trailing `\r` right now, which could cause the bad request.

Comment: @KeghamK. It might also be better/easier to use `HTTP/1.0` instead - see updated answer.

Comment: Thanks for the HTTP/1.0 part i will check with the server developer and see if his server supports 1.0

Comment: @KeghamK. You can quickly check that by changing `HTTP/1.1` to `HTTP/1.0` in your code. Almost all servers should support that.

Comment: Thanks for your support. I left it for a hour calling the server every 10 sec and im getting very good responses now from all my api routes. I just have an issue that i cannot use the esp8266 as AP & CLIENT at the same time i have to close the client connection first. My setup is WIFI_AP_STA. I really don't know if you have used esp8266 before. But if you can give me any hints that would be appreciated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131843/discussion-between-kegham-k-and-danny-ds).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Danny_ds instructions i was able to solve my issue and thought of sharing the working code in here as a reference.

```
// Read Auth reply from server and print them to Serial
  while(client.available()){

      char c = client.read(); 
      response += c;
  }
   String testStatus = response;
   if((strstr(testStatus.c_str(),"HTTP/1.1 500")) != NULL) {
    Serial.println("Found reponse 500");
    return;

   } else if ((strstr(testStatus.c_str(),"HTTP/1.1 200")) != NULL) {
      Serial.println("Found reponse 200");
      //Grabing the token after the header
      String token = response.substring(response.indexOf("\r\n\r\n") + 8 );
      //Removing the \r in end of token
      token.remove(40);
      deviceToken = token;
      writeDeviceToken(deviceToken.c_str());
      delay(500);
      Serial.print("Device Token:" + deviceToken);
      return;
   }
```